# Speeding up macro that goes through a workbook overwriting sheets by value

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I made an Excel VBA macro that goes through a workbook sheet by sheet and if the sheet contains no pivots it will overwrite it by value. Unfortunately, on at least one workbook it takes so long that I can go through each sheet myself faster. I am wondering what to do to speed it up. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to accomplish this?

```
' Convert entire workbook's worksheets to values
'
Sub workbook_overrideSheetsToValues_noSave()
    Dim answer As Long, c  As Long, ws As Worksheet, report As String

    answer = MsgBox("Overwrite formulas in this workbook?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Warning! Formula overwrite!")
    If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' only copy over by value if there aren't any pivot tables in the sheet.
        If ws.PivotTables.count = 0 Then
            Call copySheetByValue(ws.Name)
        ' save all sheets being skipped
        Else
            c = c + 1
            report = report & Chr(10) & c & ".    " & ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws

    If report <> "" Then Call MsgBox("Sheets with pivots were skipped:" & report, 0, "Warning!")
End Sub


Sub copySheetByValue(sheetName As Variant, Optional cellPos As String = "A1")
    Dim vFlag As Boolean

    ' Handle case where sheet is hidden
    If sheets(sheetName).Visible = False Then
        sheets(sheetName).Visible = True
        vFlag = True
    End If

    Worksheets(sheetName).Unprotect

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(sheetName).ShowAllData  ' Clear filters on all columns
    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' Unhide all columns
    On Error GoTo 0

    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells.Copy
    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Goto Worksheets(sheetName).Range(cellPos)

    ' Hide sheet if it was unhidden above
    If vFlag = True Then
        sheets(sheetName).Visible = False
        vFlag = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The workbook where it works really slowly has 27 worksheets with 12 containing pivots. The 15 remaining each have under 1000 rows with the exception of one containing 24000. Doing a Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C and then pasting by value only takes a moment when done manually.

Comment: I placed a msgbox announcing each sheet it overwrites and it bogs down on the one with 24000 rows. When I escape out of the macro prematurely and rerun it, the macro goes quickly through all of them including the 24000 row one. Why won't it just go through it fast the first time?

Answer (score 2):

Ben,

First thing would be to add a few controls to make sure Excel isn't allowed to calculated things:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'xlCalculationAutomatic to revert back
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.StatusBar = False
```

Then, you did a great thing using `Worksheets(sheetName)` to make sure your code really execute on the good worksheet but you should really encapsulate it in a `With` block to avoid the code to evaluate what this Worksheet object is:

```
With Worksheets(sheetName)
    ' Handle case where sheet is hidden
    If .Visible = False Then
        .Visible = True
        vFlag = True
....

    ' Hide sheet if it was unhidden above
    If vFlag = True Then
        .Visible = False
        vFlag = False
    End If
End with
```

Finally, think about writing the value to your cell instead of doing a copy-paste, because copy-paste is really slow. Think about limiting your macro to the range your worksheet really use.

```
'Supposing your data start at A1
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim EndColumn As Long
With Worksheets(sheetName)
    EndRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    EndColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(EndColumn, EndColumn)).Value2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(EndColumn, EndColumn)).Value2
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. I'll make some modifications and see what happens. I noticed a couple of things with the examples you gave. There is a typo in the "Dim EndColunm" line and after the With Worksheets line where you have "EndColumn =" instead of EndRow. Testing now, I get an error for the EndColumn line. I am thinking it may be that .Columns.Count should still be .Rows.Count? In any case, thanks for giving me something to work with. I can't assume where my data begins at A1, though most of the time it will but I don't think that should be an issue occasionally it includes everything.

Comment: Errors should be fixed now.

Comment: As for the range, keep in mind this macro will look to data in the first column and first row. If they are empty, you'll end up with a range of a single cell : A1, no matter where the data is located. So adjust the column and the row of the `EndRow = ...` and `EndColumn=...` to take a cell that you know for sure is not empty (like C3). Then, in the final statement, starting from A1 won't hurt much.